# StackOverflowException in multi-threaded UI update application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have an application where a bunch of jobs are off working (await Task.WhenAll...) and updating a progress section of a form.

I've noticed that when it is running particularly fast (e.g. when there is not much processing to do, just checks), that I'm getting the following exception thrown:

[image: StackOverflowException updating label text]

The InvokeRequired helper method was one I found on this site a while ago and looks like this:

```
    internal static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T control, Action<T> action)
        where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(new Action(() => action(control)), null);
        }
        else
        {
            action(control);
        }
    }
```

Could anyone tell me why assigning the label text value like this is causing a StackOverflowException please?

Edit:  Here is the detail of the exception

[image: Thread error]

Comment: Maybe when you assign new value, it executes some events, which executes UpdateProgress... Just debug it step by step and it will show you what is wrong.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in and step through you should be able to see the exact path that is being looped over, casuing the stack overflow. This should allow you to see exactly why the recursion is happening...

Comment: This never happens on my dev machine - this was captured on the server it was deployed to (symbols included to see what was happening).  I can put in extensive logging, but was just wondering if something stood out to anyone before going through that process.

Comment: @StanleyGoosebump: Where is the screenshot from then? You look like you have a VS breaking at the point that it is going wrong which suggests you should be able to look at the stack trace at that point, etc...

Comment: @Chris the exception detail is unavailable - the only message it gives in that screen shot is that the thread is in a state of StackOverflow.  The VS instance is one that is on the server - an ancient VS2010 but showed my this much at least when I included the symbols in the release.  The stack trace that is available is one that executed hundreds of times previously and is one that I expected.  The fact that it is a label text assignment and "safely wrapped" with the helper method is what is really strange to me here.

Comment: Why don't you look at the stacktrace. You should be able to see the overflow very very very quickly there.

Comment: @StanleyGoosebump "Safely wrapped"? The helper function does nothing to Stackoverflows, it is to prevent Cross Threading Exceptions.

Comment: @Aron Yep, I know :) I meant in that context as I was thinking that the overflowexception was possibly a red herring.  As it turns out the answer was in my question - it's doing too much (too many assignments) when it's only doing checks as opposed to processing work - I need to throttle updates as Ivan referred to below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two situations:

- you get too much requests from your workflow to update info and it breaks the application - in that case you need to do something that is known as 'debouncing' - when you get the request you don't execute the update but only set the timer to let's say 200 ms  and cancel the previous timer and timer executes the update, that way you ensure that update can't happen more frequently than once in 200 ms which won't break the app. It can be more complicated than that if you frequently get new requests in less than 200ms for long periods of time, then you need to implement the logic to update sometimes and not to trigger the timer.
- you have some circular reference that is causing the code to execute multiple times (but if that was the case you would probably get exceptions always) - you can only check this by using the debugger and checking the stack that calls the problematic code.

Comment: Thanks Ivan - your first point got me thinking - this error only manifests when the system is performing checks and not doing actual processing work.  The timer is not an option for this, but I've added an internal counter that limits until a specific point of processing is hit.  It is now zipping along fine again - many thanks.